# Name depends on the number of characters

Tags: vb.net

How to write a conditional statement acting as follows:

- If "% name%" has 1 character, name: 00 "% name%"
- If "% name%" has 2, name: 0 "% name%"
- If "% name%" has 3 , name: "% name%"

  ```
      action.SetDynamicParameter("FileName", ((((((("%version%" + "_")  _

                  + String.Join(", ", array2))  _

                  + "_")  _

                  + "%name%")  _

                  + ".jpg"))
  ```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Your code is VB.Net not VBA, please clarify which your using? (In.Net there is String.PadLeft())

Comment: Definitely not VBA...  are you trying to convert this to VBA or... ?

Comment: I apologize for mistake.

Comment: It is not batch programming either, %version% doesn't mean anything special in a vb.net program.  Use a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your just trying to pad a number as a string with leading zeros to a length of 3.  Is that correct?  If so, try this:

```
Private Function FormatMyName(ByVal Name As String) As String
    Return Name.PadLeft(3, "0")
End Function
```

If created it as a function so it's easier for you to add the additional formatting you need (e.g. adding a .jpg extension)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return of the Function for Nothing or check the length of the string before passing it to the Function.

```
Private Function GetPaddedName(OriginalName As String) As String
    Dim PaddedString As String = ""
    Select Case OriginalName.Length
        Case 1
            PaddedString = "00" & OriginalName & ".jpg"
        Case 2
            PaddedString = "0" & OriginalName & ".jpg"
        Case 3
            PaddedString = OriginalName & ".jpg"
        Case Else
            PaddedString = Nothing
    End Select
    Return PaddedString
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.